# How best to structure a page on which instances of a single model can be created or updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I am looking for a little advice on structuring the following.

I would like to display a single page. On which 3 events can be created or updated. Each event has a specific name (Open, Close, Start)

I would like user to be able to create, 1 or all 3 of the events.

Upon returning to the same url I would like the created events to be displayed for the user to Update, and uncreated events to be available for creation.

For example.

User vists events/new

Creates Event - (called Open)

No action for Close and Start.

Upon returning to events/new

Event (Open) value is displayed. To be updated.

Events Close and Start can be created new.

How would you structure this? I toyed with the idea of implementing find_or_create method.  Should this be placed in the create action in the controller, to replace the .create(params[:e.g])?

Many thanks

Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller - EventsController:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @event = Event.new
    @events_created = Event.all # to show the events created
```

In your view - events/new.html.haml:

```
- @events_created.each do |created_event|
  %p= "Event: " created_event.title

= form_for @event do |f|
  =.... # new event creation form
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in any action, looks like you are trying to combine `show`, and `new` actions as a single action. I would handle it in some custom action and then manipulate the view to show the details of the objects with a link to eidt in case someone tries to edit the object, if object isnt present already then just show the form to create object instead of showing the details and edit link.